# Why can’t the everyman get housing without the Lords of America?

Tags: society, governance, feudalism

I am continuing to evolve my [neo-feudal America](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/227018/origins-of-the-feudal-lords-of-america) after it falls from superpower status, [basing this evolution on political science research](https://web.archive.org/web/20120319221311/http://kms1.isn.ethz.ch/serviceengine/Files/ISN/96894/ichaptersection_singledocument/D52C839B-6A34-48DD-98E1-BE33926FCE17/en/chapter14.pdf) which links such an evolution to the privatization of security.

The theories in that research form the premise in my world, they are canonical. They are immutable in the story. Answers claiming “it doesn’t work like that” relying on competing political theories may as well also say Peter Pan can’t fly. It does in my story, because he does in his story.

In essence, a “Lord” is a security provider who is providing a polity essentials which the State can not or will not provide. Specifically, these are family empires or dynasties in my story. In the story, the State also lacks resources (tax dollars, manpower, and equipment superiority) to police the reforming second-world nation.

After removing one pillar of democracy in that other question, my current problem is how to physically gather the general public around the Lords, disadvantaging self-sustaining and independent communities (without making them wholly impossible).

I am planning to do this by placing housing out of reach of the common man (assuming that I have already mostly removed the middle class in the other question).

## What mechanism can give neo-feudal Lords in a post-superpower America a large advantage in providing general housing?

Free access to energy and information can both be variables in my world, but I would prefer only one of these handicaps underlie an answer.

**Note:** In my research I have found that there is a growing opinion that [South Africa has formed a neo-feudal state today](https://www.newgeography.com/content/006689-feudalism-and-stagnation-south-africa).

Comment: What does the political science research say?

Comment: When American government and State government are so weak, aren't these Feudal Lords the "new state" ? Then, what would your scenario have to do with privatizing security according to Caparini, where state and security providers remain separate, powerful entities? There won't be any laws or values imposed onto these security providers, except the laws and values of the Feudal Lords themselves. You'll get a classic army and classic police. They would be feudal armies and feudal police, governed by feudal law, set by the local Lord.

Comment: @Goodies The State is ineffectual, not absent. Like modern Haiti. Chapter 14 is the specific theory I am evolving.

Comment: Chapter 14 is your link. Caparini advocates an open mind toward privatization of security, in relation to its customer, which is the state. The customer imposes laws and values and Caparini argues that is possible. If you would follow Caparini, a government would pay your Feudal Lords to provide these services, according to and complying to government laws. She thinks that could be possible. Butin in your scenario, the Feudal Lords become actual  authorities themselves, not companies being hired by a state. They rather *override* the state's power, by exercising their economic power..

Comment: @Daron It says what is happening in South Africa.

Comment: I've put an answer, the medieval analogue plays a role.. I tried to maintain Caparini.

Comment: @Goodies I don’t think I ever suggested who the legal authority was. I know I never said the government and law didn’t exist. The government doesn’t have the resources. If Lords are contracted by the government or operate in lieu of it is a world problem open to the solution. The Caparini argument would suggest the former, and that’s fine.

Comment: @VogonPoet to have the level of control Caparini assigns to "the state", it would have to remain quite powerful, because the state actually assigns coordinators, to manage the Feudal Lords as security providers. That is not applicable to Feudal Lords in your scenario, so I've put religion in. That would provide a coordinator (bishops) and same time, the priests will serve the Feudal Lords interests, like they did in medieval times. America would become a symbolic entity playing a role in the religion's narrative.

Comment: @Goodies Definitely elements I like but your painting something closer to fascist nationalism. Which isn’t absurd.

Comment: Everyone knows Peter Pan can't fly, but why should that stop him?

Comment: The lords own all the land and have the power to police their ownership... why is it more complex than that?

Comment: "The State also lacks resources to police the reforming second-world nation." what?

Answer (score 9):

As a variant on the answer proposed by The Square-Cube Law, if the Lord is the security provider I assume he also acts as law enforcement. Very cynically, law enforcement is just a monopoly on force that allows the state to enforce their rules. The Lord is the head of law enforcement and by extension the head of state.

Now rather than just doing anything he wants, he may be able to maintain moral high ground by pointing to a set of consistent rules that are claimed to protect the citizens. Those rules may be the laws of the old United States, but they can also be "community rules" that he basically made up, or had a community assembly create.

Now, a collection of laws can accomplish the Lords monopoly on housing. For example:

1. The Lord has somehow legally acquired all property in the Stronghold (whether through confiscation, purchase or any other law, which may include laws he made himself for that purpose). The borders of the "Stronghold" is the borders of what the Lord owns. Depending on how fractured the situation is and the power of the Lord, it might be a section of land, a city, a county or larger. But anyway, to live in a Stronghold is to live on the Lord's land and to live under his protection, as his security apparatus upholds the laws against murder, theft, etc.
2. Living outside a stronghold in the Hinterlands makes you an outlaw. As in "outside the law"; you do not have the protection of the law (I.E. a Lord).
3. Depending on how things are outside the stronghold that might be an incentive in itself with bandits preying on people. These bandits may or may not be welcome to trade their ill-gotten gains at a Stronghold, or might even live in a Stronghold. People might gather together for protection out in the Hinterlands, but if anyone rises to power in such a community they basically become a Lord themselves. Though a minor one.
4. If things outside the Strongholds are not inherently dangerous, the Lord might make them so. For instance, a law might state that outlaws are inherently criminal. Why else would they live outside the reach of the law? So the Lord's patrols will range out into the Hinterlands and chase out these criminals and burn down their dwellings.
5. Lords might also allow some people to live outside their Strongholds. If the Strongholds are the centers of commerce due to their security and law enforcement, then farmers might be allowed to live untouched outside the Stronghold, as they'll have to come to the Stronghold and be pay the sales tax in order to sell their produce.

Of course, an important part is probably also that the Lords are not a monopoly. Some might own all the land and chase out freesteaders. Some might be genuine security providers. Some might welcome the presence of a neighbouring democratic city state while others would abhor it.

Answer (score 7):

#### Out Price Real-estate

The situation you are describing sounds very close to the state of what is happening in Egypt right now.

In Egypt, the average working class income is equivalent to about 148-2615 USD per month with 400 USD being considered a good income, but in many areas, the average cost of a home is over 1 million USD.  Their housing market became inflated like this because of the number of wealthy immigrants and upper-class tycoons who can afford buy these outrageously priced homes, but when native Egyptians started not being able to afford homes, the government stepped in and started providing government owned homes through massive subsidies... which further inflated the housing market to the point that no normal person can make enough in a lifetime to buy a home.

Because there is so much incentive to sell or rent overpriced housing to the government, it is worth it for the rich to invest in real-estate without actually having to be held back by real market forces.  This also gives the nobility easy access to the state coffers.  If they can build a home for 10,000\$ and sell it to the government for 1,000,000\$ then you can redirect a vast portion of the tax budget directly into the pockets of the wealthy.  This makes it almost impossible to loose money as a wealthy person or to profit if you don't already have money.

So for your Feudal USA to work, you should start by crashing the economy causing working class income to plummet.  Then blame the crash on the current trend of Keynesian economics.  This will cause the people to sway in the direction of Austrian School Capitalism to avoid deficit spending.  Since popular demand will create laws that prevent the government from abusing fiat deficit spending to fix the problem, they will need to turn to private investors for bailouts.  This will give the wealthy a LOT of pollical influence as leaders are forced to accept more and more biased deals to get the funding they need.  So, these investors will be able to push for laws and programs that advantage them in exchange for keeping the government running.  Over time these laws and programs will establish the rich as an undisputable nobility and allow them to create an outpriced real-estate market like you see in Egypt today.

Comment: Why does the government not build houses itself, rather than buying them from developers? There is clearly land available to buy and build on. Or are the developers building on land they already own?

Comment: @Daron Because the government it run by the same nobility that profits from it.

Comment: This actually sounds way too close to what already seems to be going on currently. A recent report I saw (I'll have to search for it later) indicated that IIRC around 75% of Arizona residents can't securely purchase a home in the state at current prices. I just moved out of an apartment where they were "disqualifying" existing tenants from renewing, lightly renovating, and now charging nearly double for the same space. My parents had to downsize because their property manager increased the rent by 25% on the new lease, and is now listed for 50% more than they were paying 3 months ago.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle ^ This is precisely what makes it so plausible.  We've already seen this happen in other Capitolist societies, and the USA is already several steps down the same path.

Comment: @Nosajimiki -- mostly because of screwed-up land use regs that lock 90%+ of our urban land in amber, forcing growth out of desirable urban neighborhoods to exurban edge sprawl or small patches of land that are permitted to be redeveloped into mid-rise and high-rise forms

Answer (score 4):

> (...) America (...)

## Guns

True to feudalism, every square foot of land belongs to a lord. They will be constantly checking who is building what on their turf. And if you pull a little pig and build your own cot somewhere without their permission so you can live without paying rent, you will get a visit from the big bad wolf. Only instead of blowing your house down with with his own breath, he is going to blow your house down with bullets.

If you want to keep your subscription to life you can only live in places and buildings approved by your feudal lord.

Comment: I didn’t state as such but doesn’t this paint the Lord as a dictator rather than a provider of security? That mechanism certainly existed, and is indefensible, but not ubiquitous? I prefer to paint the Lords as security providers if possible. This mechanism has often (always?) led to revolution. Maybe another way to say it is, I prefer a world solution (alter the world) over a story solution (alter the actors’ behavior)

Comment: @VogonPoet `dictator rather than a provider of security` I sincerely cannot see the difference, and I'm not even a neoliberal nor ancap.

Comment: @VogonPoet He does provide security...from other lords which is pretty unsustainable if anyone who wants to can live on his land for free.

Comment: @VogonPoet In most traditional feudal societies, the lord _was_ a dictator within their domain. Sometimes they were benevolent, but their word was law, and even if there was some higher authority (be it a king, an emperor, or some intermediary lord) it was often difficult, if not impossible, for a serf wronged by their lord to get justice. Despite this, they (usually) did provide security, because part of the basis of feudalism (just like part of the basis of being a dictator) was being able to maintain your authority over your land.

Answer (score 4):

### **New American Belief System: Houses are handed out by God. People building their own house are heritics.**

**Priests replace central government**

I'd introduce religion. Your central entity "America" should at least have *some* power, maybe symbolic power, to fit the ideas Marina Caparini advocates. Part of her conclusion is this reasoning,

> This chapter has underscored that the empirical reality on the ground –
> i.e. the multiple actors now engaged in producing security – must be the
> basis of any attempt to coordinate or control security governance. There remains a vital role for the state in providing security, but it
> is also clear that this is no longer an exclusive role; many other
> actors are now acting as security providers in developing and
> developed states, and can contribute to oversight and control. The
> state remains a vital actor in the governance of security and in
> defending the public interest.

Now in your scenario, the American state has lost control completely. It has no money, land or power. When you'd allow that, your Feudal Lords will become independent warlords, like Somalia or (indeed) Haiti. How to resolve this, to maintain Caparini's ideas, without sacrificing the rest of your story by introducing a strong federal government?

You could give a priest cast or "bishops" the coordinative task Marina Caparini advocates. They would symbolically unite the Feudal Lords under one banner, the New American Belief System.

**Houses are God's property**

In the medieval analogue: all *formal* land ownership resided with the king and the church. In your scenario, there will be Feudal Lords who own the land, sanctified by the priests. These Feudal Lords will "lend" the houses and agriculture parcels to the people, with God's blessing. Part of the new American Belief System would be, that God owns all the land and all the houses. And whoever obeys God is entitled to inhabit a house.

**Heretics**

Of course, the priest cast would decide who obeys God.. and they will defend the interests of the Feudal Lords at the same time.

Now suppose the "lending" of house, or agricultural land would be denied to anyone who wants to live far away from the Feudal Lord. These people could be designated heretics and prosecuted. Such people do not want to "borrow" a house from God, they must be non-believers.

**The church services will be in, or near the Feudal Lord's house**

This will enforce it further. A community would form, centered around the Feudal Lord's house, because people go to church there. If attending these church services would be obligatory for every American, people living far away will have a problem anyway. The middle class is gone, no one can afford a car.

Comment: European Monarchies and hence their feudal systems were always backed by the church and in turn backed the church. It's fundamental to the claim of the right to rule as a monarch that God has chosen you to do it.

Comment: @Separatrix a feudal system may not exist without a strong belief system. Any inherent,  autonomous freedom felt by man would cause trouble for the Feudal Lords.. their corruption would become visible. In this system, priests and Feudal Lords are corrupt, backing eachother up, fooling the population to worship a nostalgeous  concept of "America" that does not exist anymore. America has been fundamentally changed, freedom is absent.

Answer (score 2):

***NEO AMERICA 2077***

most of security & governement power getting in the hand of a wealthy elit? sound pretty cyberpunk to me, it's alway a question of how do you frame it. but beside joke, here are some the thing you can do to force people to live under those new lord

[I would recomand watching this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTN64g9lA2g) which is a tought experiment of how you would have a feudal society coming from off the wall capitalism. it does go a bit up there toward the end, but it would probably help you in your reasearch

**no acess to the grid**

Water and electricity  acess are extremly important, but the state either won't provide those anymore, or at least won't do the construction work itself to bring you those amenity. And the cost of those infrastructure is just way to high for any individual.

even if you could build a home yourself (which you can't really for anything more advance than a log cabin).

**But is it that different from today situation**

in a sens, it's honestly pretty much like today:  you only have acess to a home  by either paying a landlord or having a bank giving you a loan. you are forced to bow to welthier forces to get acess to hom already. just make it so you can't get a loan to buy anymore and voila

**Straight up warfare**

if the state won't do any of the security work? then it's not hard to see said lord pretty much destroy by force any settlment not under sufficient protection. depending on how evilish you want them to be, it could be common knowledge they do it, they can invent convoluted law explaining that settlement even if not on "their" propriety is still impacting their value therefore they have the right to, or for an extra degree of deniability  pay under the table some mercenary to harass them, play dumb to it

Comment: Off-grid electricity is quite plausible these days (solar + battery + an efficient house), and off-grid water and sewerage disposal is still commonplace in places that aren't cities (or are you proposing prohibiting septic tank pumping companies?).  Also, there are places where land still goes for low enough values that a cash purchase is possible (and it's even plausible to buy a home on cash still if you don't mind it being a total maintenance hog), and self-building is not as implausible as it sounds even in this day and age...

Comment: okay, im giving you solar, assuming you can source what you need to do that by yourself, install it and regularly maintain it.  off grid water is a possibility, but it is yet another undertaking. 

buying a house/land cash is something possible, i give you that, but it is not something everybody can do, because it is an undertaking that take YEARS and require many different skillset.

remenber, there is no help from compagny possible, as no lord wanting to force people living in there city would autorise compagny to do buisness to people living off grid

Answer (score 1):

## Welfare State

The Lords of America provide a big welfare state, but they want things in exchange, one of they is that you must obey the rules of the "good morals" of the Empire, and server the lords of protection.

If you have a House without the authorization of the Lords of Protection you are harming the welfare of other, thus you will be punished.

## Edit in request of the OP

First of all is necessary to recall that the definition of Socialism is

> Public ownership of the means of production (Ball et al., n.d.)

### Feudalism is a type of socialism

If you want to avoid Marxism without losing realism you must have clear what is Feudalism.

Is necessary to notice that an on-command economy (e.i. a planned economy by the planners) requires *de-facto* socialism. This is because for the planner to be able to execute their plans, they must violate private property rights, therefore making the relevant means of production *de-facto* state property, and state property is at least a form of public property.

Feudalism existed in the times before the existence of the economic sciences, at age where was thought that there is no way of gain something without harm another, as Mises reflects in this quote

> None of the great modern inventions would have been put to use if the mentality of the pre-capitalistic era had not been thoroughly demolished by the economists. What is commonly called the "industrial revolution" was an offspring of the ideological revolution brought about by the doctrines of the economists. The economists exploded the old tenets: that it is unfair and unjust to outdo a competitor by producing better and cheaper goods; that it is iniquitous to deviate from the traditional methods of production; that machines are an evil because they bring about unemployment; that it is one of the tasks of civil government to prevent efficient businessmen from getting rich and to protect the less efficient against the competition of the more efficient; that to restrict the freedom of entrepreneurs by government compulsion or by coercion on the part of other social powers is an appropriate means to promote a nation's well-being. British political economy and French Physiocracy were the pacemakers of modern capitalism. It is they that made possible the progress of the natural sciences that has heaped benefits upon the masses. (Von Mises, 1998, pp. 8-9)

In the feudalism no one can start a business because it will harm others, unless the feudal lord approves it in the grace given by their „divine right to rule“.

Feudalism is (at an significant level) on-command economy thus a veriety of Socialism.

By your other post I think that the historical form of feudalism is no far-away of your conception of neo-feudalism.

### Marx's fundamental contribution of to socialism in general

Is Important that denote that Socialism was in most practical ways refuted by the Classical Economics on the word of Ludwig von Mises

> The great upheaval was born out of the historical situation existing in the middle of the nineteenth century. The economists had entirely demolished the fantastic delusions of the socialist utopians. The deficiencies of the classical system prevented them from comprehending why every socialist plan must be unrealizable; but they knew enough to demonstrate the futility of all socialist schemes produced up to their time. The communist ideas were done for. The socialists were absolutely unable to raise any objection to the devastating criticism of their schemes and to advance any argument in their favor. It seemed as if socialism was dead forever. (Von Mises, 1998, pp. 73-74)

The qualitative contribution made by Marx for the entirety of socialism was to deny reason. In the word if Ludwig von Mises

> Only one way could lead the socialists out of this impasse. They
> could attack logic and reason and substitute mystical intuition for
> ratiocination. It was the historical role of Karl Marx to propose this solution (Von Mises, 1998, p. 74)

This fundamental contribution towards socialism by Marx can be prevented by either denying knowledge to the public, double-think, or accept the contribution of Marx in the denial of reason.

### The differentiation of Marxism from another Socialism

The characteristic idea concept of Marxism that distinguished it from another forms of Socialism is that Marxism alleges to the class division of the „Proletariat“ and the „Bourgueis“. Claiming that the „Bourgeois exploits the Proletariat“ so they must rebel against the „Bourgeois“. This class divide is the more distinctive trait of Marxism.

There is also alienation a very hard to even understand concept that, but that their principal objective is attack the traditional values, and replace their with socialism.

The Encyclopedia Britannica appears to agree that Class Struggle and Alienation are the  most important traits of Marxism.

### Welfare without Marxism

You just can prevent you of class struggle and alienation characteristics, and you would have avoided the most characteristic traits of Marxism.

Certainly Welfare State no is necessary something Marxist. As the fact that the Welfare State in the German Imperie (Stolleis, 2013).

You could made the lords of America to give a minimal welfare state (e.i. they give the minimal needed so that the populous no doubt they, after the obvious today the ration of chocolate is 10g is one gram more then the yesterday ration of 11g), where pre-capitalistic economic thought is the norm.

Other possibility would be make a cult around the Lords of America that makes their affirmations given as if they were direct gods, so they no doubt the pretext that they give by their activities. (This also is one form of enforce the previous possibility)

You said that „Free access to energy and information can both be variables in my world, but I would prefer only one of these handicaps underlie an answer.“. Certainly if you want to force pre-capitalistic economic thought you need the cult of before, restrict information or a Big Brother.

I think that force pre-capitaistic economic thought by the means of information denying is perfect for your world.

## References

Ball, T. and Dagger, . Richard (Invalid Date). socialism. Encyclopedia Britannica. https://www.britannica.com/topic/socialism

Stolleis, M. (2013). Origins of the German welfare state: Social policy in Germany to 1945. Springer.

Von Mises, L. (1981). Socialism: An economic and sociological analysis. LibertyClassics.

Von Mises, L. (1998). Human action: A treatise on economics. Ludwig Von Mises Institute.

**PD:** You are very unrealistic thinking private companies can grow bigger than any state can protect.

Comment: Expand on this, it might not be far off, in a Marxist sort of way.

Comment: You realize we have real life examples that contradict the "high welfare promotes government control" myth right? Chiefly France, which according to the World Economic Forum spent nearly a 3rd of it's GDP on social welfare in 2019 (so pre-Covid), but is also well known for having a very high frequency of civil unrest, protests, and like 60 years of chopping the heads off the rich people in charge...

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle does France impose strong morals on welfare recipients?

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle Please read again, even if defend the "welfare state promotes goverment control", I am no summoning it in the response, but I am saying that it is a perfect system of legitimization of tyranny.

Comment: @VogonPoet I sped far too much time in that

Comment: Then sorry and thank you all together!

Answer (score 1):

**Corruption**

You want a large group of Lords who form independent from the government and take over some of their responsibilities.

The Lords were originally a coalition of businessmen who became politicians, in order to support their business. For example they fiddled with the tax rates, or had the government only buy from their business and not their competitors.

Eventually they got so good at this, they transferred some of the governments responsibilities back to their business collective. They gave their companies exclusive security rights in perpetuity. Then they dismantled the military and police force and sold their second hand equioment to SecuriTech for peanuts.

Even if the leaders of the government are also the CEOs of SecuriTech, they want the job done privately, since there are fewer legal restrictions that way.

Answer (score 1):

All housing grade lumber is genetically modified to only grow under some conditions the lord controls., high tech options: radio waves, nanobots

Lowtech: fertilizer bees

Peasants get an allotment of these usable materials.
Other woods aren't strong enough or rot.

Comment: If you tried to control lumber like that, I'd just build out of light-gauge cold formed steel instead.  You'd be better off trying to wrangle control of concrete, but even then, permanent wood foundations and helical piles are both things...

Comment: This is actually doable without crazy sci-fi nanobots or genetic engineering. In the early 20th century “eucalyptus boon” entrepreneurs found fine furniture in Australia very desirable and started importing the seedling, planting them all across the West. They are useless, can’t even form railroad ties. The Aussie furniture came from centuries old trees. So, Lords deforest public lands and own all lumber grade forests. Simple. Outsiders get crappy wood.

Comment: So this answer is: Lumber trees “ only grow under some conditions the lord controls.” Yup. Lords control the land with pine and fir forests, then burned everything else down (blame the war). Matches are cheaper than nanobots ;) Then they say, “Oh, we’re sorry! We’ll plant you new eucalyptus forests.” You’ll have your new house in 300 years.