# How would a modern society be ruled by a warrior class?

Tags: society, warfare

I want to know if it is possible for a modern Western society to revert to a form of feudalism, with a warrior caste or 'knights' that rule and protect everyone else for food and money. How would such a scenario be possible with modern technology and weapons, preferably without a world ending apocalypse?

Comment: Hi Soronort, please limit yourself to one, focused question per post. This means you cannot ask both how our current society could be ruled by warriors/mercenaries and what weapon they should use. This also means you have to cut into smaller parts your problem : Right now your question is very likely to require book-sized answers to be solved. Focusing will help a lot answerers to help you in return . You can read more about how this site works in the [help-center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origins of the Feudal Lords of America?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/227018/origins-of-the-feudal-lords-of-america)

Comment: That is the plot of *your* story. How come that in your story the European civilization is rules by a feudal class? P.S. just to be helpful. Maybe in *some* countries the feudal masters were sort-of a caste. In *most* countries, they were not. For example, Eastern European boyars and English barons had no problem whatsoever to marry commoners, and they actually did. Second, they did not protect anybody for food and money. In fact, money was not very important in most European Middle Age countries. Third, the essence of the feudal class was that they controlled the land, not that they fought.

Comment: You could make a fairly compelling argument that Modern Governments fulfill your criteria.

Comment: North Korea. (filler)

Comment: Parts of America still have the elements / mindset of feudalism left over from pre-Civil War. Things like heavy promotion of and special privileges given to the "first responders", taxing people and merchants to send tax money to large entities, "tribal" voting patterns, and "don't change society" attitudes.

Answer (score 11):

**Not really.**

The feudal system is, at the core, about *personal* rights and obligations. The modern system tries hard to be about *institutions.* I owe taxes to the state, not to the president. If the president changes, that does not affect the taxes one little bit. In a feudal system, oaths would have to be reaffirmed first, and until then rights and obligations would be in limbo. That's no way to maintain a modern state.

However, various fiction writers and non-fiction analysts have speculated about certain ways in which the modern nation-state is in retreat. First globalization and then even more the internet have created a situation where *transnational corporations* slip from government oversight. The headquarters gets moved to a tax paradise and highly-paid corporate lawyers and lobbyists run rings around tax officials and regulators. (And even if it is not possible to escape regulation, just moving the tax base weakens the state.)

Some citizens react to that by taking state functions into their own hands. And if they are to weak to do it alone, they do it together with similar people. This leads to those with capital organizing these activities and gaining influence and power over those with less money.

- [Gated communities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_community) instead of normal municipalities.
- [Shopping malls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shopping_mall) with privately-owned corridors instead of shopping streets where the streets themselves are public.
- Instead of a literal [soapbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapbox) to speak to a crowd, there are social media platforms regulated by their owners.

What these points have in common is how commercial actors provide replacements of what used to be the 'commons' of a society. Access to these is 'at the whim' of the owners, and users have to purchase the right to use them. this is a step back, not towards full-blown feudalism but towards [laissez-faire capitalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laissez-faire), with capitalists controlling workers not as serfs but as [wage slaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wage_slavery). (That is, in theory the workers have a choice. In practice, it is take a raw deal or starve, because they don't have the financial reserves to go on strike.)

A slightly more dramatic situation is what you see in [Haiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiti#Post-Aristide_era_(2004%E2%80%93present)) and similar places. Read 'gang leader' for 'knight' and 'gang member' for 'troop,' and what you see there is a return to sort-of-feudal rule. So the weaponry of your knights and troops would be simple [small arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Arms_and_Light_Weapons) and the occasional [technical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_(vehicle)), because they are destroying the infrastructure to maintain anything more advanced. Look at what local craftsmen in Pakistan [can do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khyber_Pass_copy).

Answer (score 0):

Difficult but possible

First get rid of the draft.

To create neofudalism you must first create Neo medevilism. To do that you must take away the states monopoly on force and instead give the power of military force to private individuals. For that you need military companies.

The draft is what killed the private soldier as it made mercenaries not only irrealivant to the state but a liability.

However if you take away the draft and you create a need for the state to have mercenaries.

Once new mercenaries are created any one with enough money can buy them so that is how you'll get your dukes, counts, and lords.

Next you need neo feudalism

The feudal system was ultimately based around a monopoly over land the aristocracy owned all the land and rented it out to the peasants.

You will need to recreate that relationship with something else. Perhaps Technology.